# How to add an assembly reference at compile time for vbproj or csproj files?

Tags: .net, reference, assemblies, compilation

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand the question, but can't you just use the following: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5bac5fx(VS.80).aspx

Assuming you are building from Visual Studio, you can add these arguments through project properties

Comment: Yeah I am thinking of using csc but can csc build vbproj files or is limited only to build csproj files

Comment: btw, you may also want to look at msbuild

Comment: +1 for pointing to compiler commandline switchs. But I believe the */reference* command is what he was looking for, not the */lib* command. */lib* just tells the compiler where to look for assemblies, but */reference* tells the compiler to actually make a reference. For more information see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yabyz3h4(v=VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access an assembly that's not specifically referenced in your project, you can use the [System.Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.aspx) namespace. This won't actually add a reference to your project file, but it will enable you to use other assemblies.

Comment: This could help adding the assembly at run time but i need to add reference before the compile. Thnaks